# How do I query a JSON file in android without parsing the entire file?

Tags: android, json

I remember with the old twitter web service you could do something like:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blahblah

and that would return a JSON object that addresses a certain search query.

As I'm working with a fair bit of data, I'd like to somehow query the file in order to only return a JSON object that matches a specific query.

Thank you in advance for any help you guys can offer.

Comment: I think the above URL is returning response: ***The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for JSON Streaming parser. Which basically parse the specific JSON Object instead of parsing complete JSON.

As recommended go for Jackson parser http://jackson.codehaus.org/
It supports Pull Mechanism. You can have look at

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you a lot...

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:External_Data/Archive_2012

read it.It would help you!!!