# How to get data of specific ID from JSON array in my app with TextView

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON array like this

```
[{"id":"1","stdName":"Samim","department":"cse"},{"id":"2","stdName":"Karim","department":"eee"},{"id":"3","stdName":"Ovi","department":"envt"}]
```

I have a script that can retrieve all JSON arrays data but how can i get the specific id's data like sql query where clause.

How can get all data where id=1 like this below

```
{"id":"1","stdName":"Samim","department":"cse"}
```

Comment: look into [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17714826/3326331)

Comment: sorry,this is not helpful @sagar pikhwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to get full object of particular id.

```
    JSONArray jsonArray;// this is your array containing data
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jobj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            int id=jobj.getInt("id");
            String stdname,dept;
            if(id== 1)  // compare your id here
            {
                stdname=jobj.getString("stdName");
                dept=jobj.getString("department");
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can make this validation in server side wcf or php by adding an extra parameter to your url like www.202.*.*.*com/id or you can use some if condition and there you can get remaining id's data . It is better to have validation from server side so that you can get only the required record data and that will decrease data size and improve performance .